# MD5 as idempotentKey in Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache, apache-camel

The default behavior is that the absolute file path is used to uniquely identify files - I would like customize this to use the md5 checksum of the file.

Is it possible to simply implement a custom idempotentKey (that doesn't use the 'File Language')?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Camel File2 component supports pluggable expressions. Create bean implementing [Expression](http://camel.apache.org/expression.html) and pass it to route with `idempotentKey=#myExpressionBean`.

---

I don't think, it is good idea to compute md5 hash of file content for every poll, but it is possible.

**Expression**

```
@Component
class FileContentMD5Expression implements Expression {
    @Override
    public <T> T evaluate(Exchange exchange, Class<T> type) {
        if (type != String.class){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("This is String only expression");
        }
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(((File)exchange.getIn(GenericFileMessage.class).getGenericFile().getFile()))) {
            return type.cast(DigestUtils.md5Hex(fis));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Consumer**

```
from("file://somewhere?idempotent=true&idempotentKey=#fileContentMD5Expression")
```

Comment: Excellent - works, thank you. You say that it's not a good idea to compute an md5 hash every time - is there a better way to check for unique files that you would suggest?

Comment: Is this working. I think we can't use expression for file component because file component's idempotentKey parameter only supports String and not expressionDefinition. 

It will work for idempotentConsumer but not for file ...right?
@Bedla